# How to abort submit when exception happens?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe payment and my code works all the time but if exception happens, I can't handle exception in a HttpPost submit.

This is the entry point after user clicks on button:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Checkout_Stripe()
{
    return PayWithStripe();
}

public ActionResult PayWithStripe()
{
    ... some codes here ...
    try
    {
        ... some codes here and exception happens ...
        return Json(new { id = stripeSession.Id });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ... execution reached here but even with below redirect, I still get HTTP 404.
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart");
    }
}
```

and my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('my stripe key');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('stripe-checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fetch('https://localhost:44323/Cart/Checkout_Stripe', {
                method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

This is what I get in browser:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
> are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
> had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
> the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Cart

Comment: Is your controller called `CartController`?  Because that error complains that `/Cart` doesn't exist

Comment: Yes. it is CartController

Comment: You have a `RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart");` which might be related but `/Cart` in any case is not a Stripe API endpoint. What's the except that causes you to hit that codepath? Presumably you expect to create a checkout session, but you haven't shown that code or the initial error.

Comment: @NolanH, everything works fine if exception does not happen. and in case of exception, I redirect to Cart,Index to show an error message to user. I don't know if showing the code for checkout session will help or is relevant. it's a verbose code but if it can help, I will include it in my question.

Comment: Ah so the Checkout session code works most of the time? And this issue is only when that exception arises for other reasons? If so that's really not something I'm able to help with, it's going to be something to do with the MVC framework/routing.

Comment: Right. I updated my question to be more clear. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to handle the errors in below part of JavaScript

```
.catch(function(error) {

    // in case of error, I need to redirect to error page here
    window.location.href = "/Cart/GatewayRedirectFailed";

    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```